# Signal to filter in R

Tags: r, signal-processing

I need to filter a signal without it losing its properties so that later this signal is inserted into an artificial neural network. I'm using the R and the signal library, I thought about using a low-pass filter or an FFT.

This is the signal to be filtered, it is about shifting pixels in a video. In the case I calculated the resultant of vectors X and Y to obtain only one value and thus generate this graph / signal:

[image: Normal sign]

Using the signal library and the fftfilt function, I obtained the following signal, which seems to be easier for a neural network to be trained, but I did not understand what the function is doing and if the signal properties have remained.

```
resulting <- fftfilt(rep(1,50)/50,resulting)
```

[image: Filtered signal]

Could someone explain how this function works or suggest a better method to filter this signal.

Comment: I get that you are going to use this as input to a neural network, but other than that this is nothing to do with NN, recommend removing the tag. I'm inferring that this is using a fast-fourier transform, in which case you're asking an academic question and not a programming one. Perhaps this would be more appropriate at [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It seems that you want to design a filter, i.e. you can filter a signal and feed it into a Neural Network. So essentially, you are asking how to design one black box to make a second black box happy. Without narrowing down the problem this question is very hard to answer.

Comment: That is a really poor signal. Are you sure there isn't a way to collect better data? I've collected a lot of data from many different types of systems, and in my experience, data that bad usually indicates a fundamental problem with your acquisition. This is important because from the perspective of the analysis and how you have to treat it, there is no signal with "properties": all you have is what's in the data, and there's no *a priori* intrinsic difference between signal and noise. Maybe there's a property (like frequency components) that separates the two, but rarely perfectly.

Comment: The signal represents pixel displacement in a particular region of a video, it would be the signal generated by a certain movement. Not how to collect better data, because the movement always generates a similar signal, the problem is in the neural network, I find it impossible to train it with a signal so varied, so I would like to transform that signal.

Answer (score 0):

As for the fftfilt(...) function I can tell you roughly what it does: it is an approximate finite impulse response filter implementation that uses FFT of the filter impulse response function with some padding as a window. It gets the signal's FFT within the window and filter's IR FFT, then generates the filtered signal in frequency domain by just multiplying the two results and then uses the reverse FFT to get the actual result in time domain. If your FIR filter has a huge number of coefficients (even though in many cases it is just a sign of a bad system design and should not be needed) the function works much faster than filter(Ma(...),...). With more reasonable number of coefficients (like definitely below 100) the direct and precise approach is actually faster.

As for the proper methods of filtering there are so many of them that there are full thick books on just the topic. And my personal experience in the field is a little bit skewed towards somewhat specific very low computing power microcontroller-based sensor signal DSP tricks with fixed point arithmetics, precise unity gains in a selected pass band point, power of 2 scale coefficients and staged implementations so I doubt it would help you in this case. Basically first you just need to know what result do you want to get from your filter (and do you even need to filter or maybe just something like peak detection and decimation is enough) and then just know what you are doing. From your message it is hard to guess what your "neural network" requirements are, what you think you need for it and what you actually need.